# How do I change the color of a hyperlink on mouse over of an image?

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

I'm building a webpage that has a little piechart on it.  The pie has 6 pieces and to the right of this image, I have the text hyperlinks that a person could optionally click, to go to the same place that clicking the piece of pie will take them.

The hover property is set to change the color of the hyperlink on mousehover.  Is there a way I can also hover over the image pie piece and still make the text hyperlinks change color, just as if I was hovering over them?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to implement a javascript solution for this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a container, and apply the hover function to that container.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/mrS5b/1/)

CSS:

```
.container:hover a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Alternatively use the CSS + selector to select the next sibling element
See this updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/mrS5b/2/)

Comment: That gets very strange to do that with the different slices of a pie

Comment: See my updated answer. Now it should only select the next element

Comment: but you still have a problem with the piechart. how do you integrate all the pie slices in your containers with the links without destroying the piechart?

Comment: This actually works great for my needs.  What a cool site too! (jsfiddle).  I don't have to use a pie for my needs, so I'm changing a bit to make this work. Thanks so much!